# Automatically select Date above 2000 for Datepicker in Vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin14

I want to implement a Datepicker where the Keyboard entry of "22" as year is automatically set to "2022". Same goes for all two digit years. I also want to support localized Date formats as the product is used all over the globe.

So the I18nDatepicker component where I can specify formats like "dd.mm.yy" does not help as it would reject the US standard format for instance. What I came up with is this small ValueChangeListener:

```
    datePicker.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
        datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.of(
                datePicker.getValue().getYear() % 2000 + 2000,
                datePicker.getValue().getMonth(),
                datePicker.getValue().getDayOfMonth()
    ));
```

The problem is that "setValue" method will again fire a change event if the dates are different (which they are to Vaadin). So ALL change listeners of this component will be executed twice, once with the twodigit year and with the correct year. This could also be database queries, which is no good.

A custom datepicker component extending from Datepicker can not solve this problem (to my knowledge) unless I change the "getValue" method which doesn't really sound like a good solution to me.

Anything I overlooked? Other ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set multiple date formats using `DatePickerI18n` class, e.g.

```
DatePicker picker = null;
DatePickerI18n i18n = new DatePickerI18n();
i18n.setDateFormats("MM/DD/yyyy", "MM/DD/yy);
i18n.set... // Populate the whole i18n object using all the setters
picker.setI18n(i18n);
```

Comment: First of all thx for your comment. The problem with this is germans put the day first which would be dd/mm and Americans put the Month first mm/dd. Is there a way I can decide which format to use based on the locale or smth ?

Comment: Yes, you can use formats that fit you, I am just presenting the API how it is set.

Comment: The problem is I think the API does not support the format that fits me.
My format would be any digits of Days and Months (1-2) followed by 2-4 digits of years which are always set past 2000. But I need to adjust the order of days and months according to the local the user has. Vaadin does the local support for 4 digit years pretty well, but I have not found a way to make custom formats for each local.